# Cannot resolve method findViewById(int) - Edit Text to Date Picker

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, findviewbyid

Can anyone tell me what the error is with my code shown below. Trying to use Edit Text to open a date picker dialog but it's showing error cannot resolve method findViewById(int)

```android
package com.example.claire.townapp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
EditText txtdate;
public DateDialog(View view){
    txtdate=(EditText)view;
}
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


// Use the current date as the default date in the dialog
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);


}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    //show to the selected date in the text box
    String date=day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
    txtdate.setText(date);
}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();


    EditText txtDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
    txtDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus){
            if(hasfocus){
                DateDialog dialog=new DateDialog(view);
                FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");





    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: while in fragment try getView().findViewById

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're code isn't working is because findViewById(int resID) isn't a method on Fragment like it is for Activity. You need a valid object such as a  view to call  [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById(int)). AlertDialogs happen to have a utility method that allows you to check its layout for a View similar to View (in fact, behind the scenes it's simply passing the call through to its own View object 'mWindow'). Get a reference to the dialog and and call [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById(int)) passing a reference to the EditText you want.

I don't believe your code will work because you don't have any control over your layout since you are simply wrapping a DatePickerDialog with a fragment. Be careful since you are using a framework class you need to be aware of the View's inside of its window. For example. I peeked into the source code of DataPickerDialog and I didn't find any references to a View with the id of 'txtdate' or even a EditText (I may be wrong, didn't look to thoroughly). Passing that value in to findViewById(int resid) you will return a null. You could also get a ClassCastException, if it happens to contains a View with that id but of a different View type, so pay special care to view type as well.